# Call global function within a method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, frontend, javascript-objects

I've done some leg work on getting this code to behave the way I want it to up to a certain point. 
However I have encountered problem that requires a little bit of direction in helping me to solve the issue.

Problem to solve
Comments in code will explain what I am trying to archive..

```
var myArr = ["Brent white","brentw.white"];

function nameFoo (name){
 var strSplit = name.split(" "); // splitting Brent White
 var nameStr = this. myArr; // fetching Brent white string from myArr
console.log (strSplit,myArr[0]);
}

nameFoo("Brent White"); // calling nameFoo function 

var myData = {
  someData:"somedata", 
  someMoreData:"moredata", 
  myName:function(){
// I need to call nameFoo function through myName method.
// My hypothesis is that return will use the (this) keyword within the object?    
  }
};

// Here I need to call the method to have access my nameFoo? Correct me if I am wrong? 
// Is this method invocation?
// Please help..Lost here...
```

To sum it up, I want `myName` method to call the `nameFoo` function. `nameFoo` will then give me `myName` method the result.

If someone could be kind enough to demonstrate how to get through this last step then I would be very grateful.

Pointing me in the right direction would also be greatly appreciated..
PS I am new to JS.

Comment: 1. `myName: nameFoo` 2. Remove `this` in your `nameFoo`

Comment: Your use of `this` in `nameFoo` appears to be misguided and is likely the cause of your confusion or problems.  Make `nameFoo()` just operate on arguments that are passed to it and return a result and then you can just call it from `myName()`.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with the 'this' keyword.  By calling nameFoo in a global context ie:

```
// some code 
nameFoo(arg);
// some more code
```

'this' will always refer to 'window'.  So, when you call myData.myName, even though this object calls the nameFoo method, 'window' will still be referenced in nameFoo's 'this'.  'this' is normally scoped to the object the function belongs to.

If you need 'this' to refer to one of your custom objects, use the Function prototype method "call" from within your myName function.

```
var myData = {
   ...
   ...
   myName: function() {
      nameFoo.call(this, someArgument);
   };
```

Note that someArgument will be the argument passed to 'nameFoo' -- which will throw an error if you do not supply an argument.  It's up to you to figure out what you want to pass.

More info about Function.prototype.call:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

More info about Function.prototype.apply:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

The only real difference between the two is how you supply arguments to the function you are calling.  With "call", you separate the arguments with commas (as you would when normally executing a function).

eg: `nameFoo.apply(this, arg1, arg2, arg3);`

With "apply", you supply the arguments as an array.

eg: `nameFoo.apply(this, [arg1, arg2, arg3]);`

Comment: thanks @DRAB for a detailed explanation..I have been working on getting this but I still seem to be having issues with pulling my name from `myArray` Please check out this bin. http://jsbin.com/hevizo/1/edit?js,console seems like I don't know what to put in as the argument within my `cutName` function call..

Comment: I think that most of your confusion is being caused because you are approaching JavaScript from a conventional object-oriented perspective.  JS is very different.  I've changed your jsbin to give you some examples http://jsbin.com/dejenaxizi/2/edit?js,console  I don't have time to explain it all to you, but you can find more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking this conceptually may help you out:

```
// Some names in array
var my_names = ["Brent White", "John Smith"];

// Returns name array [First, Last]
function nameParse(full_name) {
    return full_name.split(" ");
}

// Person object (properties)
function Person(name) {
    this.full_name = name;
    this.name_array = nameParse(name);
    this.first_name = this.name_array[0];
    this.last_name = this.name_array[1];
}

// Create single person example
var brent = new Person(my_names[0]);

// Access properties of brent
console.log(brent);
console.log("Hey, my first name is " + brent.first_name);

// Alternate example --------- //

// Store our people here
var my_people = [];

// Create a person for each name
for (var i = 0, max = my_names.length; i < max; i += 1) {
    var some_person = new Person(my_names[i]);
    my_people.push(some_person);
}

console.log(my_people);
```